# Combining JSON Arrays with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've spent all morning messing with this now and reading on here, but have found myself going round in circles!

I am trying to draw a chart using the excellent `AmCharts` Javascript Charts, to show me stock holding as a bar chart and stock turn as a line chart.

I cannot get both sets of data from one query to my database, and cannot use AmCharts StockChart as it is not time based data... therefore, I have two sets of data which need combining with Javascript.

The data is being pulled from a database and returned successfully as JSON arrays similar to this:

**SALES DATA:**

```
[{"brandName":"Fender","gearShiftedPerMonth":"35","retailSalesPerMonth":"55"},
 {"brandName":"Gibson","gearShiftedPerMonth":"23","retailSalesPerMonth":"43"},
 {"brandName":"Epiphone","gearShiftedPerMonth":"10","retailSalesPerMonth":"13"}]
```

**STOCK DATA:**

```
[{"brandName":"Gibson","stockValue":"1234"},
 {"brandName":"Fender","stockValue":"975"},
 {"brandName":"Epiphone","stockValue":"834"}]
```

Obviously the actual figures are made up in that example!

Now, what I need to do is to combine those to create this:

**COMBINED DATA**

```
[{"brandName":"Fender","gearShiftedPerMonth":"35","retailSalesPerMonth":"55","stockValue":"975"},
 {"brandName":"Gibson","gearShiftedPerMonth":"23","retailSalesPerMonth":"43","stockValue":"1234"},
 {"brandName":"Epiphone","gearShiftedPerMonth":"10","retailSalesPerMonth":"13","stockValue":"834"}]
```

What we have there is the Sales Dataset combined with Stock Dataset to add the additional data of `stockValue` added to the corresponding brandName record.

I have tried using `$.extend` but I can't figure out how to use it in this situation.

It is perhaps important to note that the data pairs might not necessarily be in the right order, and it is possible, though unlikely, that there might not be a match, so some kind of zeroing error catching must be implemented.

Comment: Why can't you get both sets of data from one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what's he's trying to do is join the two datasets as if they were tables, joining by the brandName. From what I've been testing jQuery's $.extend() function does not take care of that, but merges objects according to their index in the Object arrays that it receives.

I think the matching of the key would need to be done manually.

```
stock = [{"brandName":"Fender","gearShiftedPerMonth":"35","retailSalesPerMonth":"55"},
 {"brandName":"Gibson","gearShiftedPerMonth":"23","retailSalesPerMonth":"43"},
 {"brandName":"Epiphone","gearShiftedPerMonth":"10","retailSalesPerMonth":"13"}];
value = [{"brandName":"Gibson","stockValue":"1234"},
 {"brandName":"Fender","stockValue":"975"},
 {"brandName":"Epiphone","stockValue":"834"}];

var results = [];
$(stock).each(function(){
    datum1 = this;
    $(value).each(function() {
        datum2 = this;
        if(datum1.brandName == datum2.brandName)
            results.push($.extend({}, datum1, datum2));
    });
});
```

Which would result in:

```
[{"brandName":"Fender","gearShiftedPerMonth":"35","retailSalesPerMonth":"55","stockValue":"975"},
{"brandName":"Gibson","gearShiftedPerMonth":"23","retailSalesPerMonth":"43","stockValue":"1234"},
{"brandName":"Epiphone","gearShiftedPerMonth":"10","retailSalesPerMonth":"13","stockValue":"834"}]
```

Instead of what the use of `$.extend()` returns:

```
[{"brandName":"Gibson","gearShiftedPerMonth":"35","retailSalesPerMonth":"55","stockValue":"1234"},
{"brandName":"Fender","gearShiftedPerMonth":"23","retailSalesPerMonth":"43","stockValue":"975"},
{"brandName":"Epiphone","gearShiftedPerMonth":"10","retailSalesPerMonth":"13","stockValue":"834"}]
```

Comment: This is correct.  However, see my answer below for a slightly different approach that would be more efficient for very large data sets at the expense of memory.

Answer (score 4):

What you'll need to do first is transform the data into two objects, whose properties are the values you want to merge together:

```
{
"Fender" : {"gearShiftedPerMonth":"35","retailSalesPerMonth":"55"},
"Gibson" : {"gearShiftedPerMonth":"23","retailSalesPerMonth":"43"},
"Epiphone" : {"gearShiftedPerMonth":"10","retailSalesPerMonth":"13"}
}
```

and

```
{
"Gibson": {"stockValue":"1234"},
"Fender": { "stockValue":"975"},
"Epiphone": { "stockValue":"834"}
}
```

Once the transformation is done, you'll have two objects that you can merge using `$.extend` or other functions.

*Update*

For large sets, this gives results in nearly linear time:

```
var salesa = {}, stocka = {};
$.each(sales, function(i, e) {
    salesa[e.brandName] = e;
});
$.each(stock, function(i, e) {
    stocka[e.brandName] = e;
});

var combine = {};
$.extend(true, combine, salesa, stocka)
```

More speed can be tweaked if the merging happened during the second transformation callback (`$each(stock...`) instead of a separate call to `$.extend()` but it loses some of its obviousness.

Comment: No need to transform the data out of an array.

Comment: @jholloman: Transforming the data will ensure that data between brand names match up. Notice that in the question, the brand names don't consistently align with the Array indices. +1

Comment: Sorry I made the wrong assumption that the extend solution was correct. What would you propose as the most efficient way of transforming to an object?

Comment: @jholloman No problem.  I updated the answer to give an example that runs in nearly linear time, unlike the other answers which require doubly-nested loops.  This uses more space, but runs in far fewer instructions.  It could be tightened more as indicated or if I dropped the jQuery calls and used straight-up JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

If your example code reflects reality, then jQuery's `$.extend` will be the *wrong* tool for this.

It blindly copies data from one object to another. Notice that the order of your data is not consistent. The SALES DATA has `Fender` first, while the STOCK DATA has `gibson` first.

So jQuery's `$.extend` is mixing the two results. The "gearShifted" and "retailSales" for `Fender` is ending up with the "brandName" and "stockValue" for `Gibson`.

---

What you'll need is to iterate one array, and look up the "brandName" in the other, and then copy over the data you want. You could use `$.extend` for that part of it if you like...

```
var sales_data = 
[{"brandName":"Fender","gearShiftedPerMonth":"35","retailSalesPerMonth":"55"},
 {"brandName":"Gibson","gearShiftedPerMonth":"23","retailSalesPerMonth":"43"},
 {"brandName":"Epiphone","gearShiftedPerMonth":"10","retailSalesPerMonth":"13"}]

var stock_data = 
[{"brandName":"Gibson","stockValue":"1234"},
 {"brandName":"Fender","stockValue":"975"},
 {"brandName":"Epiphone","stockValue":"834"}]

var combined = $.map(sales_data, function(obj, i) {

    return $.extend({}, obj, $.grep(stock_data, function(stock_obj) {
        return obj.brandName === stock_obj.brandName
    })[0]);
});
```

---

*Note that this is not terribly efficient, but unless the data set is enormous, it shouldn't be an issue.*

---

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/sDyKx/

***RESULT:***

```
[
    {
        "brandName": "Fender",
        "gearShiftedPerMonth": "35",
        "retailSalesPerMonth": "55",
        "stockValue": "975"
    },
    {
        "brandName": "Gibson",
        "gearShiftedPerMonth": "23",
        "retailSalesPerMonth": "43",
        "stockValue": "1234"
    },
    {
        "brandName": "Epiphone",
        "gearShiftedPerMonth": "10",
        "retailSalesPerMonth": "13",
        "stockValue": "834"
    }
]
```

Comment: I thought I was wrong, got down-voted and deleted my answer to reduce clutter.  I should have stuck to my guns.

Comment: @clintp: Undelete your answer, and I'll give you +1. Yours is another good solution if the data can be transformed.

Comment: If you *knew* there was a 1:1 relationship it might be quicker to sort the arrays by the `brandName` and then merge from there.  The solutions here are all O(N*M) at worst, and a sort could be as low as O(log N * log M).  This is why I took a transformative approach at first.

Comment: @clintp: Yes, you're right. If the data can be transformed as you showed, that would be a far better solution. Sorting could help, but would probably only make sense if the data needed to be repeatedly accessed as separate sets. Since the data is being merged, the separate sets are a bit obsolete. Assuming the data *can't* be transformed on the server, I'd probably build your data structure on the client, instead of sticking with Array lookups.

Comment: Oh, for some reason I have only just spotted all these extra answer on here. I'm always in favour of whatever uses the fewest lines of code. @clintp and "am not i am" your answers are very nice. My data isn't massive, but I am still after efficiency. Which wuold be you guy' recommendation? On a slight tangent, clintp can you point me to an article that explains the maths you mention? O*N*M) etc

Answer (score 1):

In vanilla javascript you can do:

```
var sales = [{"brandName":"Fender","gearShiftedPerMonth":"35","retailSalesPerMonth":"55"},
 {"brandName":"Gibson","gearShiftedPerMonth":"23","retailSalesPerMonth":"43"},
 {"brandName":"Epiphone","gearShiftedPerMonth":"10","retailSalesPerMonth":"13"}];

var stock = [{"brandName":"Gibson","stockValue":"1234"},
 {"brandName":"Fender","stockValue":"975"},
 {"brandName":"Epiphone","stockValue":"834"}];

var combined = stock.slice(0);     

for (var i = 0; i < stock.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < sales.length; j++) {
        if (stock[i].brandName === sales[j].brandName) {
            for (var attrname in sales[j]) { combined[i][attrname] = sales[j][attrname]; }
        }
    }
}

JSON.stringify(combined)
```

produces

```
[
{"brandName":"Gibson","stockValue":"1234","gearShiftedPerMonth":"23","retailSalesPerMonth":"43"},
{"brandName":"Fender","stockValue":"975","gearShiftedPerMonth":"35","retailSalesPerMonth":"55"},
{"brandName":"Epiphone","stockValue":"834","gearShiftedPerMonth":"10","retailSalesPerMonth":"13"}
]
```